# How can I save user inputs into an array during runtime?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have been working with lists a lot so I got this done with that, but I am trying to use another data structure such as an **array**.

My code below works fine and when I enter my full name + phone number, it prints as it should. But since I am using a switch case, if I go to another case, the previously entered values (full name + phone number) are all gone.

```
case 2:
    Console.WriteLine("Enter first name:");
    string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter last name:");
    string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your phone number:");
    int mobileNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine(firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + mobileNo);
    break;
```

I am using a console application for this and I don't need to save values into a text file, just on the screen until I close my program. I have been able to do this with existing array values, just not with user inputted values, so this is what I've ended up with.

Comment: Why an array? Why not just move the declaration of firstName etc. out of the loop?

Comment: And BTW: phone numbers are not integers. You cannot do arithmetics with them, leading zeros are significant, and they can be longer than an integer can hold.

Comment: Well, the values are gone because you don't store them anywhere, you just get them with `ReadLine` and otput them with `WriteLine`. After exiting your case statement those variables can no longer be used. And if you mean, that they are gone from console output, then that have nothing to do with storing the values, there might be a stray `Console.Clear()` in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try removing the variable declarations out of the loop. So they will still be available when faced with a different case.

```
//declarations out of your loop.
string firstName ="";
string lastName = "";
int mobileNo=0;
List<string> lines=new List<string>();  
//end of declarations.

//your loop or whatever you have here.
switch()
// your cases.
case 2:
    Console.WriteLine("Enter first name:");
    firstName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter last name:");
    lastName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your phone number:");
    mobileNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    lines.Add(firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + mobileNo);
    break;

//end of switch statement iterate over lines list to print all lines.
foreach(var line in lines){
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this earlier before creating my post, however when I enter a new first name, last name and mobile number, it replaces my previous entry, rather than adding to it (to a new line). I was looking into a foreach loop to prevent them from disappearing but had no luck

Comment: Instead of printing in case2, I added the line to be printed in a list called lines. At the end of the process, I put a loop that will print all the rows in the list. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Yeah this is basically what I was going for. I'll adjust it based on my code but that helped a lot. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In C# in case if you don't know how many items you'll have in collection it is better to use List.

I would solve your task like this:

1. Declare a class that describes your object. (In your case it is User)

   ```
   internal class User
   {
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return $"Full name: {FirstName} {LastName}, Phone Number: {PhoneNumber};";
       }
    }
   ```
2. Declaration list of Users:

   ```
   var usersList = new List<User>();
   ```
3. Input data:

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("Enter first name:");
   string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

   Console.WriteLine("Enter last name:");
   string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

   Console.WriteLine("Enter your phone number:");
   int mobileNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   ```
4. At the iteration end:

   ```
   usersList.Add(new User
   {
       FirstName = firstName,
       LastName = lastName,
       PhoneNumber = mobileNo
   });
   ```
5. In case if you want to log your list:

   ```
   foreach (var user in usersList)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(user);
   }
   ```

Full code:

```
internal class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Full name: {FirstName} {LastName}, Phone Number: {PhoneNumber};";
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var usersList = new List<User>();

        switch() // your switch
        {
            case 2:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter first name:");
                string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter last name:");
                string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter your phone number:");
                int mobileNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                userList.Add(new User
                {
                    FirstName = firstName,
                    LastName = lastName,
                    PhoneNumber = mobileNo
                });
                break;
            }
        }
        
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user);
        }
    }
}
```